# More Speed for 4,1 Mac Pro?

Tags: mac, memory, ssd, pci-express

I'm using an early 2009 Mac Pro, 4,1 2.66Ghz, 32 GB memory, 2TB HDD, GeForce GT 120.

Tried the hack to 5,1 and it would not complete even though SIP was disabled.  So won't be using Sierra, stuck with El Capitan. That's ok since it works fine. So my questions are about more speed. I bought a Samsung 860 SSD 1TB and will use it on a PCie card.

1. I've seen the questions about TRIM. How do I turn it on after inserting the SSD?
2. Will Disc Utility work to format SSD?
3. Will Carbon Copy Cloner work to clone a bootable OS onto the SSD? I really need an exact clone. If not, should I download and install El Capitan from the Apple store? And if I do that will I lose the setups and prefs for all my apps?
4. Anyone know of a way that will work to update to 5,1? The one from Fixit didn't work.
5. If I can get to 5,1 will I then be able to use more RAM and higher speed?

Thanks to all of you who can help out. I'm 84, a disabled Vietnam Vet living on Social Security and cannot afford to upgrade my computer. I'm in the process of designing a website using Dreamweaver so I can try to earn an income as an affiliate. So I really do need to increase speed on the Mac Pro.

Comment: “So I really do need to increase speed on the Mac Pro.” Why do you need more speed to design a website? I’ve been designing, developing, deploying and debugging websites since 1995 and speed is never a need for website development. Regarding the SSD questions, you are overthinking this: An SSD will work fine with your system and definitely speeds some things up. An SSD will also work fine with Disk Utility and Carbon Copy Cloner. Regarding TRIM and your attempts to hack your system to fake being a 5,1 system, the risks outweigh the benefit. Just install that SSD, clone it and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help on the 5,1 firmware update, I'm afraid - I bought my FrankenMac 5,1 already updated, with 2 x 6-core Westmeres already done.
As to the rest…

TBH, you won't see a huge difference in speed by putting the SSD on a PCIe card to get SATA III speeds. In practical terms, sure it's faster than SATA II, but not enough to warrant the price of the extra card. You could save money & just put it in the optical bay, don't even really need a drive adaptor. As you're unlikely to be going jogging with a Mac Pro, you can just put it in loose ;)

You can enable Trim using Cindori's [Trim Enabler](https://cindori.org/trimenabler/) which will run on El Cap.
Because of the way Trim worked on El Cap Macs with 3rd party enablers, maybe every 6 months or so you should run a manual full trim from Trim Enabler. This is slightly wearing on the SSD 'cell' structure, but used very sparingly if you feel the SSD is slowing over time, will put the spring back in its step again. Newer Macs & OSes avoid this issue themselves.

Updating the firmware alone will gain you little but the ability to run Sierra unless you also plan on updating the processors to Westmeres instead of Nehalems.

Your GT120 will be holding you back a bit as well. I'd at least see if you can find a cheap ATI HD 5770 (I just checked eBay UK & they're around £45 these days. Get genuine Apple if you go for a 5770) if not an HD 6950 - newest ATI/AMD card natively supported, though you have to make sure to get a Mac-flashed one for least trouble, there is no genuine Apple version of this, so choose carefully.
The HD 6950 in a 5,1 takes your official macOS support up as far as Mojave, as it has Metal2 support, which even in a non-firmware-flashed 4,1 might be advantageous if you go the following route…

If you don't go the firmware & GPU upgrade route, you can get Sierra on that mac by using dosdude's patches - full list at http://dosdude1.com/software.html Note that the newer you go with these patches, the more likely you are to have issues, as your hardware is not officially supported. eg, you might be OK with Sierra, but definitely don't go for Catalina ;)
These patches are unofficial but as far as I'm aware do not break Apple's basic licensing terms, ie you have a Mac, you can have macOS. You're just 'caveat emptor' with it being unsupported.

Disk Utility should be perfectly capable of formatting the new SSD to HFS+ - just choose the entire 'disk' not any partition & format as GUID/MacOS Extended (Journalled)

Carbon Copy Cloner is perfectly capable of cloning your old HD to SSD & it will also offer to make a proper Recovery Partition afterwards. The result will be immediately bootable, but double-check once up & running that it is set as the default Startup Disk in System Prefs.

You can use 16GB RAM modules - again, make certain they are Mac-specific. Mac Pros use ECC RAM & are very fussy about exactly which chips.
There is also a slight hardware limitation, depending on whether you run dual- or triple-channel RAM. This means on a single CPU you can run either 4x8GB = 32GB or  3x16 = 48GB (you cannot run 4x16), or on a dual CPU 8x8 or 6x16. You need the 5,1 firmware to run more than 48 or 96GB respectively. Triple-channel is faster than dual, of course, but I don't have any Mac here running triple, so I don't know in practical terms how much difference it would make.